# How to get Value from One textbox to another instantly on a single form c#

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

I have four textboxes on a Form in windows form. They are named: `ID, Session, Class, Section`. I need to generate the `ID` in `ID_txtbox` instantly as soon as Session, Class and Sections are inserted and save it to DB. ID will contain `(Session+Class+Section)`.

Problem is how can I get data on a single form from these three txtboxes `(Session, Class, Section)` and get a special `ID` without clicking any button ?

Comment: using text changed event ? Using focus loss on any of the textboxes ?

Comment: Hm, when are you going to save this data to DB, I mean on what event do you want to do that?

Comment: Got it.... I wonder why didnt it click in my Mind... just set the on textchanged function of these three text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [TextBox.TextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event and validate if the input matches your requirements. If so, save to your database. It's possible to attach all textboxes to the same event by the way.

I'm assuming you need to generate the ID yourself, if so you can use the [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) class for this.

Comment: Yup I managed to do that.... can u please tell me how can I show a label on empty fields when user press submit? c#

Comment: ErrorProvider class is the basic approach in Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

Ok as I can see you just need to use TextChanged event for all Session+Class+Section fields, for example:

```
public class MyForm:Form
{
 private TextBox txbId;
 private TextBox txbSession;
 private TextBox txbClass;
 private TextBox txbSection;

 protected void InitializeComponent(){}//init all form's controls

 public MyForm()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  //When some of the fields are changed then ID field is changing as well
  txbSection.TextChanged+=OnTxtChanged;
  txbClass.TextChanged+=OnTxtChanged;
  txbSession.TextChanged+=OnTxtChanged;
  //use separate method when txtId changed
  txbId.TextChanged+=OnIdTxtChanged;
 }

 private void OnTxtChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
   txbId.Text = txbSession.Text+txbClass.Text+txbSection.Text;
 }

 private void OnIdTxtChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
   //save your txbId.Text in DB here
 }
}
```